# how open Qdialog in other .py module

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt

I have done a GUI interface with Qt designer and compiled the .ui file into a .py file. In main window I have this class:

```
class Projektdlg(QMainWindow, ui_Projekt.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Projektdlg, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connect(self.actionCalibration, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.CalibrationSettings)
```

I want to open the `QDialog` from the generated *ui_calibration* file when clicking on *calibration* from the tool bar. How to do that?

```
def CalibrationSettings(self):

    Dialog = ui_calibration.Ui_DialogCalibration()
```

All modules are imported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class myDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_DialogCalibration):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
```

Then in your class:

```
Dialog = myDialog(self)
```

Then you can call `Dialog.show()` or `Dialog.exec_()`

Comment: @TomislavKres checkout my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14226906/1006989), I added some more information on how to build your `QDialog`

Comment: If i want pass list to new-open dialog, with the code same as you write up, how do that?
can I just add onu more argument in __init__ function or?

Comment: @Error I can help you with that, please create another question and mention me in a comment so I am notified